# Estimate lambda for panel count data

Tags: poisson-distribution, panel-data, count-data, poisson-process

I have panel count data for $F$ firms across $I$ years, so observe counts $C_{f,i}$ for $f \in \{1,...,F\}$, $i \in \{1,...,I\}$.

I want to model the data as a poisson process. With increasing $C_{f,i}$, $\lambda_{f,i}$ will converge on $C_{f,i}$. But for firms with small $C_{f,i}$ (sometimes zero), the rate parameter should vary less across years than the observed count (this is why I want to estimate $\lambda$).

All of that said, how might I go about estimating a $\lambda_{f,i}$, given that only one count is observed for any firm-year? The typical MLE - the mean - obviously doesn't work in this case, as it equals the count.

I assume I should be using previous counts (e.g., incorporating $C_{f,i-1}$ into the estimate of $\lambda_{f,i}$). However, I don't quite know how to go about that.

My apologies if there is a simple, established answer here. I don't know much about panel count models. If it matters, I'm interested in the change of the firm-specific rate parameter from one year to the next, and cannot use the count because for some firms, the count goes from 0 to 10 from one year to the next, while others go from 10,000 to 11,000. So by comparing the rate paramaters, rather than the counts, I'm hoping to get a measure of year-to-year changes that is more comparable across different firm sizes.

Comment: How about a Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) Model with an AR(1) working correlation matrix using a Poisson distribution?